# In-App Purchase suddenly not working in IOS simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am developing an App that utilizes In-App purchases.  I used Ray Wenderlich's excellent tutorial to get the purchases working properly.  Up to now I've had no problems. However since updating to the new version of Xcode (5.0) I have run across a problem.  The In-App purchases to not work in the simulator.  They STILL WORK on my iPhone, but not in the simulator. I have not changed any of the code since updating to Xcode 5.0.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241) as of now.